# How to find common pattern of two NSStrings?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, nsstring

For example:

```
NSString *file1 = @"Invoice1";
NSString *file2 = @"Invoice2";
```

How to find the common pattern (i.e. `@"Invoice"`) of the above `NSString`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `NSString`'s `-commonPrefixWithString:options:` method.